# Zxing Mobile Crashing my App Java.Lang.RuntimeException

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing

Hey here are the logs Im receiving a second before the crash:

```
04-17 14:24:26.224 D/ZXing.Net.Mobile( 2929): Checking Number of cameras...
04-17 14:24:26.224 D/ZXing.Net.Mobile( 2929): Found 2 cameras...
04-17 14:24:26.227 D/ZXing.Net.Mobile( 2929): Found Back Camera, opening...
```

And here is the error

```
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)
```

Im 99% sure its zxing fault how can I fix that?

Im using zxing to scan the qr code and then send request to my api, retrieve data and send it to view using MVVM.

Always these 3 lines prior to every crash.

Comment: did you fix the related issue?

Comment: @MaxPinto did either os use fix this having exact same issue after 3x scann it only shows up for me